# How to open TCP port 7777 in control panel?

Tags: networking, aws

I am initiating file transfer using tcp on openfire server. But I am not able to open the port number 7777, from which I need to send files. I changed the security setting in the admin console panel of the aws. But still when I tried to send the files I am getting the error.

I tried to change the custom TCP rules, by opening only the 7777 port. But still I am not able to resolve it. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the firewall entirely - it serves no purpose.  FTP needs to establish a connection back to your computer from the server on another random port to transfer files.

Comment: let me brief u about the application which I am developing I have installed open fire xmpp chat server in the server and I am trying to initiate the p2p, that means sending files from one mobile to another mobile via port 7777, which is a default port in openfire server, but I am not able to open that particular port. Thanks a lot for guiding me